# How to add transition sliding image for my slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slideshow

Im working in an image slider. What I was able to do is very simple, and I want to add a transition effect like image sliding , or something like that. If someone knows how to add it to my code it would help me a lot. Here is what I did so far:

```css
.banner-container {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 z-index:0;
 height:100%  !important;
 background: no-repeat center center scroll
}
.banner-container.nomgr { 
 margin-top:0px;
 
}
.banner-container-center { 
 margin-top:-105px;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 z-index:0;
 
}

.banner {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 z-index:0;
 height:120  !important;
 background: no-repeat center center scroll
}
.banner-full-height {
 width: 100%;
 height:auto;
 position: relative;
 z-index:2;
 
}
.banner-center {
 width: auto;
 position: relative;
 z-index:2;
 
}
```

```html
   <div class="banner-container revolution">
                <div class="banner">
                    <ul>

                        <li > <img src="/images/slide1.png" /></li>

                        <li > <img src="/images/slide2.png" /></li>

                       <li > <img src="/images/slide3.png" /></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your code to add the effect. Change the image source before using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
        margin: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0px;
    }

.ani-top{position:relative;animation:animatetop 0.5s}
@keyframes animatetop{from{top:-500px;opacity:0} 
to{top:0;opacity:1}}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div  style="max-width:500px">
  <img class="slidetop ani-top" src="file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/download%20(1).jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="slidetop ani-top" src="file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/download%20(2).jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="slidetop ani-top" src="file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/download.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="slidetop ani-top" src="file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/download%20(3).jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var pos = 0;
slideshow();

function slideshow() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slidetop");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  pos++;
  if (pos > x.length) {pos = 1}    
  x[pos-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(slideshow, 2500);    
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```